# Change bits of text specification / fontface (bold, italic,...) in a kableExtra table cell

Tags: r, text, formatting, r-markdown, kableextra

I'm trying to format individual bits of text in a kableExtra table in rmakrdown, such as the example below:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---
```{r, echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(data.frame(char = c('Hey *italics*','Hello **bold**', 'Hi ~~strikethrough~~~'),
             num = c(1,2,3)))
```
````

[image]

However, if I use kableExtra

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
knitr::kable(data.frame(char = c('Hey *italics*','Hello **bold**', 'Hi ~~strikethrough~~~'),
             num = c(1,2,3)))
```
````

I'll get:

[image]

I know there is `cell_spec, row_spec and column_spec` to format entire rows columns and cells, but that's not what I want.

I want to **format only part of the text in a certain cell, but keep all functions from kableExtra** for designing my table. There is also `text_spec()`, but I did not find any example on how to use it within a table.

P.S. I'm not that advanced and therefor would prefer working examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix for this is to tell `kable()` to produce a Markdown table:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
knitr::kable(data.frame(char = c('Hey *italics*','Hello **bold**', 'Hi ~~strikethrough~~~'),
             num = c(1,2,3)), format="markdown")
```
````

`format="pandoc"` also works, but `format="latex"` (which I think would be the default here when `kableExtra` is involved) does not.

However, as pointed out in the comment, `kableExtra` doesn't support `markdown`, so you can't add all the nice features from that package.  If you want that, the only solution is likely to use LaTeX markup instead of Markdown markup.  That is, change the input to this:

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:  \usepackage{soul}
---
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
knitr::kable(data.frame(char = c('Hey \\textit{italics}','Hello \\textbf{bold}', 
                                 'Hi \\st{strikethrough}'),
             num = c(1,2,3)), escape = FALSE)
```
````

You need `escape = FALSE` to tell `kable` not to display the LaTeX markup as text, but to leave it there for LaTeX to interpret.

Comment: That works, but I lose all functions from kableExtra.